# I can not run my application

Tags: android

in my android studio i cant run my app and all project fill are scattered ,

firstly i got error in load the plugin I try go to sitting and add the plugin but still the problem 
 ,can you help me to fix that [image]

Comment: No, i cant help you with that if i cant even understand the question. Explain the problem you are facing

Comment: Your image shows no errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click Run down arrow button on the menu and then Edit Configurations... then click on Android Application on the left and click the + button. Choose Android Application from the pop-up menu. Then pick the module will be app . Then click apply and ok.